# Serverless custom domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless

I want to setup a custom domain with the serverless framework and AWS.

This is what I have in serverless.yml

```
service: chapiLabs-rest-api

plugins:
  - serverless-domain-manager
  - serverless-express

custom:
  customDomain:
    domainName: chapitime.chapilabs.com
    basePath: ''
    stage: ${self:provider.stage}
    certificateName: '*.chapilabs.com'
    createRoute53Record: true

package:
  exclude:
    - node_modules
  include:
    - dist

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs8.10

webpackIncludeModules:
  forceInclude:
    - mysql
    - mysql2
    - sequelize

functions:
  get:
    handler: dist/get.get
    events:
      - http:
          path: v1/client/{id}
          method: get
          request:
            parameters:
              paths:
                id: true
  create:
    handler: dist/auth.auth
    events:
      - http:
          path: v1/auth
          method: post
```

I used this npm package as plugin: https://github.com/amplify-education/serverless-domain-manager

I added a certificate via DNS using CloudFlare

[image]

Then I made a deploy and got the next log.

[image]

In cloudflare I added a CNAME to add the ACM validation and another CNAME pointing cloudfront.

[image]

But the domain name is not working. Any ideas why? I didn't bought the domain in AWS.

Comment: How have you configured this domain in CloudFlare?

Comment: I edited my question to add the cloudflare info

Comment: Observing your configurarion using `dig`, it looks like something has changed since you added the cloudflare configuration.  Your DNS record now points to a different Distribution Domain Name than the one shown here, `d33gyq....cloudfront.net` and it appears to be working.  What changed?

Comment: For some reason the cloudfront url changed and I didn't noticed before making this question. I changed and it started working. So now I just hope the cloudfront url doesn't change after deployments.

Answer (score 5):

After some deployments the cloudfront url changed and I didn't noticed. I just updated the CNAME record in CloudFlare and it started working.